# Is there a reason to ignore the decree to pound the pillars?

Tags: super-mario-64

Is there anything I miss if I don't "pound the  pillars" in the basement of the castle? Am I making any of the stars inaccessible by doing so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you'll miss something if you don't pound them; no, it has no negative effects.

> Pounding the pillars drains the moat around the castle, allowing you access to the Vanish Cap level.  That level has one star, from the 8 red coins.

Answer (score 6):

You can safely pound the pillars, you will gain access to new stars.
And as a matter of fact, no star is missable, you can still pound the pillars later.